# Git LFS fails with small files

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-init

Suppose I have files of different size of type .bin
These files may be large and small.

I want to use git lfs to work with big binary files.
I have folder in which i want to init my repo.
Its Content:
[image]

I want LFS to track all files of type .bin because they can be large and there are lot of them in a project. That is why I created .gitattributes and added .bin type there.

I have file A.bin of size 13 MB and file B.bin of size 132 Bytes.
I wrote the following script for this question.

```
git init --initial-branch=main
git lfs install
git add -A
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin <my-repo-url>
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

It work when I copy A.bin into folder, but fails with B.bin.
Message:

```
LFS upload failed:
  (missing) B.bin (489a843398d18a6a259886c01cbd86aee92e8764ceea7f77447604ff148cee8f)
Your push was rejected due to missing or corrupt local objects
```

Comment: Show us the content of the `.gitattributes`, please

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.
Turned out that file B.bin had following content

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:489a843398d18a6a259886c01cbd86aee92e8764ceea7f77447604ff148cee8f
size 1859
```

I dont know how this content came there, it was binary.
Seems like this text gives some directives to LFS and that is why I had problems.